# Create a view with multiple column and rows of cascading dropdownlists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, rows, cascadingdropdown

I am migrating from an ASP.NET web pages application to MVC 4. I am pretty new to MVC - but have found no clear direction on how to create a view (with model and controller of course) that represents a database record with several similar but different fields.

For example: the record (behind the model) is from a physical therapy exercise table. Therefore it has (basically) a patient number - visit number - and the exerciseType - duration and reps (e.g. exercise1 duration1 reps1 exercise2 duration2 rep2 .... etc.

I need to create a controller and a view with multiple columns and rows. ANY suggestions (even at a high level) would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do and recommend for this cases is to uses **ViewModels**. A **ViewModel** contains the information and fields your View needs, because sometimes our business models aren't just enough. This [tutorial](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-use-viewmodel-with-aspnet-mvc.html) may help you with it, it's one of the best way to learn how to use **ViewModels**. Let me know if you need more clarification about it.